# converting ordinal date to dd-mm-YYYY date

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I am trying to convert an ordinal date generated using `datetime` (eg. 730411) into a format DD-MM-YYYY.
My pandas dataframe `df` looks as follows:

```
0    730411.0
1    730412.0
2    730413.0
3    730416.0
4    730417.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

I tried using the following code:

```
import datetime as dt
df[0].map(dt.datetime.fromordinal)
```

Thanks.

Comment: This might work for you, you need to convert the data type from float to int. `df[0].map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromordinal(int(x)))`

Comment: `fromordinal` expects integers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.ix[:, 0].astype(int).map(dt.datetime.fromordinal)
```

It takes the first column by position.